# Разный порядок выполнения кода в chrome и ff

Tags: javascript, html

Такой код:

```html
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('setTimeout-1')
  }, 0);
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('setTimeout-2')
  }, 0);
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('setTimeout-3')
  }, 0);
</script>
<p>paragraph-1</p>
<script>
  alert('one');
</script>
<p>paragraph-2</p>
<script>
  alert('two');
</script>
<p>paragraph-3</p>
<script>
  alert('three');
</script>
<p>paragraph-4</p>
<script>
  alert('four');
</script>
```

В *Firefox* сначала выполняется по порядку весь сценарий, а только потом происходит вызов `callback-функции setTimeout`. А вот в *Chrome* сначала `alert(one и two)`, затем `callback-функции`, а уже потом все остальное. Почему так происходит?

Comment: возможно, разница в реализации парсинга html/скриптов

Comment: например, ff распарсив N тегов скрипт, начнет их выполнять, не доходя до конца страницы, а гугл сначала дойдет, а потом выполнит все, ну это предположение

Comment: @MoloF _что касается самого JS, то он выполняется асинхронно_ это где такое вы прочитали? Прям весь?

Comment: проблема заключается в реализации `alert` если его заменить на неблокирующую функцию поведение становится одинаковым

Comment: @Grundy заменил на console.log, но все равно выполняется по разному. В хроме сначала выполняется callback-функции, а потом появляются параграфы. В ff появляются параграфы, а потом callback-функции выполняются.

Comment: @Topik, на глаз не заметно отображаются ли сначала `p` или строки логов. Однако порядок логов становится одинаковым и у chrome и у FF.

Comment: @Grundy согласен. Но параграфы явно по разному отображаются почему-то.

Comment: что значит по разному отображаются?

Comment: @Grundy сори, я из callback-функций не убрал alert. Теперь действительно разницы не видно.

Comment: @Grundy но это не отменяет моего вопроса. Меня интересует именно с alert.

Comment: очевидно - разная реализация в браузере.

Comment: @Grundy вот я и хочу узнать как реализовано.

Comment: @Topik, тогда смотри исходники. Например [исходники хрома](https://github.com/chromium/chromium) или [исходники ff](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev)